# How remove double quotes from postgres table and field names on django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm working on a django project with postgres where table and field names are generated with
double quotes. Anyone knows how can I disable this behavior?

[Model definition]

```
class Test1(models.Model):
    key = models.UUIDField('key', db_column='KEY', editable=False, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = models.CharField('name', db_column='NAME', max_length=128, null=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Test1'
```

[Migtation]

```
operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Test1',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('key', models.UUIDField(db_column='KEY', default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True, verbose_name='key')),
                ('name', models.CharField(db_column='NAME', max_length=128, verbose_name='name')),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'Test1',
            },
        ),
    ]
```

[DDL Generated]

```
create table "Test1"
(
    id serial not null constraint "Teste4_pkey" primary key,
    "KEY"  uuid not null constraint "Teste4_KEY_key" unique,
    "NAME" varchar(128) not null
);

alter table "Test1" owner to postgres;
```

[DDL Expected]

```
create table Test1
(
    id serial not null constraint "Teste4_pkey" primary key,
    KEY  uuid not null constraint "Teste4_KEY_key" unique,
    NAME varchar(128) not null
);

alter table "Test1" owner to postgres;
```

[requirements]

- django==2.1.10
- django-choices==1.6.1
- django-cors-headers==2.4.0
- django-environ==0.4.5
- django-extensions==2.1.4
- djangorestframework==3.8.2
- django-filter==2.0.0
- drf_yasg==1.14.0
- ruamel.yaml==0.15.100
- drf-nested-routers==0.91
- dj-database-url==0.5.0
- requests==2.22
- whitenoise==4.1.3
- dry-rest-permissions==0.1.10
- django-polymorphic==2.1.2
- psycopg2==2.7.0
- elastic-apm==4.2.2
- brutils==1.0.1
- Jinja2==2.10.3
- schedule==0.6.0
- pika==1.1.0
- python-jose==1.4.0

Comment: I believe this is by design in django.  Note, you are specifying the db_column name as uppercase which will be lost if the "" aren't there.

Comment: are these double-quotes giving you some problem/error?

Comment: Thanks @BjarniRagnarsson, The upper case letters was making this behavior of framework as Sanjay mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @BjarniRagnarsson, The upper case letters was making this behavior of framework as @Sanjay mentioned.

Solution:

```
class Test1(models.Model):
    key = models.UUIDField('key', db_column='key', editable=False, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = models.CharField('name', db_column='name', max_length=128, null=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'test1'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is by design in Django, and it is intentionally designed in this way. this is a parametrized way.
suppose someone has a column name with spaces like `test column name` then think what would happen.
it will lead to some unwanted errors, so don't change the underlying logic of the framework.